# same entities with different forms

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have an admin and sales team member user. Problem is that Whenever I inspect any of these two entities: Contact, Organization(Account) forms differ from each other. When I check the customization I see that forms have no specific security role for Sales team member users, so what's the problem, why can't I get same entities to behave alike.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was indeed in form security roles, I was looking for the different thing.